# bootstrap img causing html and body not full length

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, overflow, responsive

New to Bootstrap and trying to layout a very simple page.

When adding the img element ('Great price') below, this causes some sort of gap down the right-hand side on portable devices, and the html and body elements no longer cover the full page. I have tried adjusting this using CSS and adjusting the row class to row-fluid etc., however after many hours, I still can't find the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\brian\Desktop\Web Design\Traders web\TemplateOne.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Template One</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-#674c8a .bg-#e23c3a">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Joe Bloggs Electrics</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>Tel: 077777777777</li>
           </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img src="C:\Users\brian\Desktop\Great Price.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%">
            </div>  
    </div>


        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>Plymouth and surrounding areas</h2>
            </div>  
    </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-pound-sign fa-8x"></i>
                        <p>Pricing</p>                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment-alt fa-8x"></i>
                        <p>Testimonials</p>                 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-8x"></i>
                        <p>Contact</p>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--    <div class="row-fluid">
    <footer>
        <p id="copyright">Copyright: Joe Bloggs Electrics</p>
    </footer>
</div> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your CSS?

Comment: Read the Bootstrap docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ -- .row-fluid doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3 or 4

Comment: I`ve reverted to using only this CSS as I try to figure out the issue:

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%
 }

I`ve also deleted -fluid but it`s still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing the `img-responsive` class with `img-fluid`. Because some classes updated in bootstrap 4 version ...